# No Service FOSJsRoutingBundle in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Bug:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 

"You have requested a non-existent service "C". Did you mean one of
these: "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController",
"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
```

How can I turn on FOSJsRoutingBundle in symfony 4?

bundles.php:

```
FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

routes.yaml:

```
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

layout.html.twig:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you use webpack? If yes then no need to include this code to the template:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

All you have to do is run this command:

`bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js/fos_js_routes.json`

Then include this code to your .js file on the assets folder:

```
const routes = require('../../web/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
Routing.generate('rep_log_list');
```

This guides is refer to this documentation: [FOSJsRouting Usage](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)